# JEditorPane unexpected behavior with new lines

Tags: java, swing, jeditorpane

I am trying to highlight text in a `JEditorPane` text field and save the index of the selected text. However I keep running into problems when I save the selections. The JEditorPane seems to save new lines in a different way each time. It will write a `"\n"`, a `"\r"` and sometimes even a `"\r\n"` when the user presses the enter key. And sometimes the JEditorPane will even ignore carriage returns which causes wrong selection indices.

Is it possible to get a consistent behavior when the user presses the enter key?

Comment: You'll need to post a [minimal, complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which reproduces the behavior you're seeing. `JEditorPane`'s behavior with new lines is documented in the JavaDoc for [`DefaultEditorKit`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/swing/text/DefaultEditorKit.html) (linked from [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/swing/JEditorPane.html#), towards the bottom of the class-level doc) and what you're describing is different from that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you using a JEditorPane. That is for displaying HTML and HTML generally doesn't have line breaks. You use the "br" tag in HTML. For normal text you should be using either a JTextPane or JTextArea.

> I am trying to highlight text

The text in a string depends on the component you are using and whether you get the text from the Document or the component.

In general you should get the text from the Document since the Document only stores the "\n" so you should be able to calculate the offset correctly and highlight the text.

When you get the text from the component, the platform new line String is inserted in the text which would cause your offset problems.

See [Text and New Lines](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/02/07/text-and-new-lines/) for more information.

Comment: I am using a JEditorPane because i want to highlight text. I save the indices of the highlights in a database and then I generate the highlights using the indices I saved previously. Because I get unexpected behavior from the enter key presses, the highlights don't correspond anymore with the original highlights.

Comment: @Ferre12, `I am using a JEditorPane because i want to highlight text` - you can highlight text in any text component. Again, JEditorPane is only for HTML. It doesn't sound to me like you are using HTML.